# In Razor allow HiddenFor to hold empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ViewModel defined like this:

```
public class ProfileSnapshotViewModel
{
    public Guid ProfileSnapshotId { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
    //...
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

And my MVC is set like this:

```
<td class="Cell">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProfileSnapshotId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsActive)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Salutation)
    //...
```

When I set up the model I set it up like this:

```
 return PartialView("_additionalreviewerrow",
            new ProfileSnapshotViewModel
            {
                IsActive = true,
                Salutation = ""
            });
```

However, my ModelState.IsValid continues to be false when submitting, saying 'Salutation is required'.

What can I do to ensure the HiddenFor is holding the empty string, and validation doesn't complain?

(This is part of a larger chunk of code, so if you think something else could be affecting it, please comment and I'll try to add it.)

Comment: if it's required then you cant have empty string.. if it can be empty then dont make it required.. if you want blanks in the database then add a default value of ''

Comment: Empty string is different than NULL. We do not want NULL.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings(v=vs.110).aspx  read the remarks

Comment: I think your model somewhere must indicate that field is required. If I'm understanding correctly this is my best guess, otherwise try model.IsActive.ToString() and see what happens.